# How to deactivate Li-Ion battery charger

Tags: usb, lithium-ion, charger

I have a USB device, which does have a Li-Ion internal battery in it. The device charges the battery when plugged into a socket.

However, I don't want that battery to be used at all, I do prefer that the device only works when the device is plugged into a power socket, and uses power supply to power itself.

Battery type is Li-Ion, fully charged around 4.2V, other specs unknown.

I already tried to replace the battery with jumper cable, thinking that if the battery charger wouldn't detect voltage drop, it would fool the device to stop charging. Nothing happened however, and the device didn't turn on with power cable on.

Also tried to run the device without the battery, didn't work.

Ideas how to replace the battery from the circuit?

Comment: (1) Why short circuit the battery? That means you have the charger running into a short-circuit. This will cause the power-supply to shut down and possibly destroy the device if it hasn't got built-in protection. (2) Why do you want to replace the battery? You should be removing the battery and see if the unit works without it.

Comment: (1), I was lazy, not too familiar with electronics, and accepting the risk that I'd destroy the device. (2) The device doesn't work without the battery, tested. (added to the main question)

Comment: Sorry, the device actually works without battery. Tried it before, but didn't remember to press the correct buttons after that. My mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on an incorrect premise that the OP has since retracted.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the device actually works without battery. Tried it before, but didn't remember to press correct buttons after that. My mistake.

Comment: Ok then delete question